# Convertation to Glint from float

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I want to get *Glint from glm::mat4x4.

I try to use  GlProject (...,viewMatrix,..)

It is glm::mediump_float there and i don't know how to translate it to Glint. Is there any function or anything that way?

I tried just

```
GLint viewport[4];
viewport[0]=float(viewMatrix[0]);
```

, but it is not okay.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Something tells me you don't understand the relationship between the view matrix and the viewport... (hint: they're not directly related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array of `GLint`s from a `glm::mat4x4` then you need to declare a new array and fill it with the values of the matrix.

```
GLint newArray[16];
newArray[0] = (GLint) viewMatrix[0][0];
newArray[1] = (GLint) viewMatrix[0][1];
...
```

I'm explicitly casting the float to an int here, but it will usually "autobox"/autoconvert this to an int for you.